# How to create zoomable images in matplotlib axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm building an interactive TSNE display showing image examples that cluster together.  My current implementation does this by creating OffsetImage objects wrapped by AnnotationBBox.  Each OffsetImage contains an image that is resized to (75, 75) pixels and they are rendered in the data space coordinate system.

The images currently appear visually the same size after each zoom (using the magnifier tool in matplotlib window).  Ideally, I'd like to be able to scale the images up as I zoom into the data space more, to allow for closer investigations into certain clusters.

Ideally, I would prefer to keep each image at full resolution (or down-scaled maintaining aspect ratio) and manually updating the scale parameter of the OffsetImage after each zoom event.  But I'm unsure of how to either retrieve or compute the zoom factor of the view and what events I would need to listen for.

Below is how I am creating the images.  Ideally, I would like to just update the zoom parameter of any Offsetimage based on how zoomed in the figure is at any time.

```
for i in indices_to_render:
    pt = self.points[i]
    url = self.image_urls[i]
    img = img_dict[url]
    logging.debug('rendering image of size: %s for pt: %s from url: %s', str(img.shape), str(pt), url)

    offset_img = OffsetImage(img, zoom=1, picker=True)
    ab = AnnotationBbox(offset_img, pt, bboxprops=dict(edgecolor=border_color), xycoords='data')
    ab.set_picker(True)
    offset_img.set_picker(True)

    self.artists.append(self.ax.add_artist(ab))
    self.images.append(offset_img)
```

Comment: `offset_img.set_zoom(5)`?

Comment: I would want to gradually update the zoom based on the zoom of the figure itself.  So if the figure were perfectly aligned with the image, the zoom would effectively be 1.  Just wondering if it's possible to compute what the zoom factor would is as the figure is zoomed in.